# transforming Tags using XSLT and XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation, xslt-3.0

I would like to use this example for a future conversion using XPATH.
Just one of them, if analizyer find e.g  'bcaExercise' that should be convert to element 'exerciseBca' without any values that contains in unitial xml. Just transforming tag to another one.
 convert to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<option>
      <abcExercise>
        <earliestExerciseTime>
          <hourMinuteTime>00:00:00</hourMinuteTime>
        </earliestExerciseTime>
        <expirationTime>
          <hourMinuteTime>11:00:00</hourMinuteTime>
        </expirationTime>
      </abcExercise>
      <bcaExercise>
        <earliestExerciseTime>
          <hourMinuteTime>00:00:00</hourMinuteTime>
        </earliestExerciseTime>
        <expirationTime>
          <hourMinuteTime>11:00:00</hourMinuteTime>
        </expirationTime>
      </bcaExercise>
      <cbaExercise>
        <earliestExerciseTime>
          <hourMinuteTime>00:00:00</hourMinuteTime>
        </earliestExerciseTime>
        <expirationTime>
          <hourMinuteTime>11:00:00</hourMinuteTime>
        </expirationTime>
      </cbaExercise>
</option>
```

This is my vision of this code. But I have no idea what exectly I should add that can find my     initial element by XPATH.

```
<xsl:template match="option">
    <xsl:element name="exerciseAbc">`
    </xsl:element>
    
    <xsl:element name="exerciseBca">
    </xsl:element>
    
    <xsl:element name="exerciseCba">
    </xsl:element>
  
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post what you are expecting as an output, your description of what you are trying to accomplish is not clear to me.

Comment: @Sebastien  if analizyer find e.g 'bcaExercise' that should be convert to element 'exerciseBca' without any values that contains in unitial xml. I mean what kind of xsl: i should put my XPATH? /option/abcExercise

Comment: @lamfitz, since it seems English isn't your first language, it would be much clearer if you showed both the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="abcExercise">
    <exerciseAbc></exerciseAbc>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="bcaExercise">
    <exerciseBca></exerciseBca>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="cbaExercise">
    <exerciseCba></exerciseCba>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Would give you this output :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<option>
  <exerciseAbc></exerciseAbc>
  <exerciseBca></exerciseBca>
  <exerciseCba></exerciseCba>
</option>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor would produce the output you show?

Comment: Whats special with the output? I wanted to test it out with an XSLT 1.0 engine so I used MSXML 6 in xsltfiddle.

Comment: Try it with any other processor and you will see.

Comment: <exerciseAbc></exerciseAbc> becomes eg <exerciseAbc/>, but that's equivalent.

Comment: We see 3 differentExercises. When ONE of them will be selected for our Input, I would like receive just ONE Output tag. But I need to create some template, for theese 3 elements, where if e.g will select  <cbaExercise> and my Output is   <exerciseCba>. Without values inside. Just transformation name of elements. @Sebastien

Comment: So I need just simply change the name of output elements. But only ONE element from core xml will be available. I put3 elements inside as the maximum values that can be.

Comment: Where and how do you get that input?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/option" name="changingNameOfElements">
        <xsl:for-each select="/option">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="abcExercise">
                    <xsl:element name="exerciseAbc"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="bcaExercise">
                    <xsl:element name="exerciseBca"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="cbaExercise">
                    <xsl:element name="exerciseCba"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

This is what I expected was! I find this result and its works! Thanks to everyone who trying to help me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).